# How to easily remove count=1 on aliased field in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in a table:

```
GROUP1|FIELD
Z_12TXT|111
Z_2TXT|222
Z_31TBT|333
Z_4TXT|444
Z_52TNT|555
Z_6TNT|666
```

And I engineer in a field that removes the leading numbers after the '_'

```
GROUP1|GROUP_ALIAS|FIELD
Z_12TXT|Z_TXT|111
Z_2TXT|Z_TXT|222
Z_31TBT|Z_TBT|333 <- to be removed
Z_4TXT|Z_TXT|444
Z_52TNT|Z_TNT|555
Z_6TNT|Z_TNT|666
```

How can I easily query the original table for only GROUP's that correspond to GROUP_ALIASES with only one Distinct FIELD in it?

Desired result:

```
GROUP1|GROUP_ALIAS|FIELD
Z_12TXT|Z_TXT|111
Z_2TXT|Z_TXT|222
Z_4TXT|Z_TXT|444
Z_52TNT|Z_TNT|555
Z_6TNT|Z_TNT|666
```

This is how I get all the GROUP_ALIAS's I don't want:

```
SELECT GROUP_ALIAS
FROM
(SELECT 
  GROUP1,FIELD,
  case when instr(GROUP1, '_') = 2
then
substr(GROUP1, 1, 2) || 
ltrim(substr(GROUP1, 3), '0123456789')
else
substr(GROUP1 , 1, 1) || 
ltrim(substr(GROUP1, 2), '0123456789')
end GROUP_ALIAS
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY GROUP_ALIAS
HAVING COUNT(FIELD)=1
```

Probably I could make the engineered field a second time simply on the original table and check that it isn't in the result from the latter, but want to avoid so much nesting. I don't know how to partition or do anything more sophisticated on my case statement making this engineered field, though.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all the great replies below. Something about the SQL used must differ from what I thought because I'm getting info like:

```
GROUP1|GROUP_ALIAS|FIELD
111,222|,111|111
111,222|,222|222
etc.
```

Not sure why since the solutions work on my unabstracted data in db-fiddle. If anyone can spot what db it's actually using that would help but I'll also check on my end.

Comment: Not answering your question, but: Can you have digits anywhere in the resulting "engineered" "field"? (Quoted: what do you mean by "engineered" - calculated? And "field" is called "column" in SQL.) If not, you could "engineer" the "field" more easily with a single application of `translate` - something like `translate(group, 'a0123456789', 'a')` (alas the odd-looking `'a'` is needed, due to Oracle's negligent handling of `null` vs empty string). By the way, does **GROUP** work for you as a column name? I would expect it to clash with a reserved keyword.

Comment: You are right, I was abstracting my code when I chose 'GROUP' and it would be a reserved word. Switched to GROUP1. Unfortunately, the CASE statement and logic behind GROUP_ALIAS has to remain fixed as it's really integral to remain constant to the system it supports. But fyi the engineered field can have digits after the underscore as long as it follows the first letter. E.g. T_99M99X -> T_M99X

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, using analytic `count`. If you are not familiar with the `with` clause, read up on it - it's a very neat way to make your code readable. The way I declare column names in the `with` clause works since Oracle 11.2; if your version is older than that, the code needs to be re-written just slightly.

I also computed the "engineered field" in a more compact way. Use whatever you need to.

I used `sample_data` for the table name; adapt as needed.

```
with
  add_alias (group1, group_alias, field) as (
    select group1, 
           substr(group1, 1, instr(group1, '_')) ||
               ltrim(substr(group1, instr(group1, '_') + 1), '0123456789'),
           field
    from   sample_data
  )
, add_counts (group1, group_alias, field, ct) as (
    select group1, group_alias, field, count(*) over (partition by group_alias)
    from   add_alias
    )
select group1, group_alias, field
from   add_counts
where  ct > 1
;
```

Comment: I like this solution and it is teaching me a lot. But in my actual query against prod I am getting the unexpected result I amended to my post. It's probably above and beyond what I asked but curious if you know what it looks like is happening with the DB to get my posted result.

Comment: Something about the count(*) over partition is making it like that.

Comment: @MarkMcGown - I don't understand your edit (update). Are you saying that in the same column `group1`, in addition to values like `Z_52TNT`, you may also have values like `1111,2222`? That is a completely different format. What is the `group_alias` in that case? There was not a hint of anything like that in your original post.

Comment: Agreed, it is weird, but that is what I really get, unfortunately. The values in Field are being replicated into comma delimited strings corresponding with the group they are in. So if the GROUP_ALIAS has a count of two FIELD's in them, then the partition after the WITH clause will replace the actual GROUP_ALIAS's with the comma delimited string of the FIELDS exactly as I've shown in the update. But if I Select * on the CTE name it doesn't have this issue. Only if I do any grouping/partitioning on the CTE as I show in the update, I get 111,222 if FIELD's 111 and 222 are in the same GROUP_ALIAS

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle  you can use REGEXP_REPLACE and analytic functions:

```
select Group1, group_alias, field
  from  (select group1, REGEXP_REPLACE(group1,'_\d+','_') group_alias, field,  
         count(*) over (PARTITION BY REGEXP_REPLACE(group1,'_\d+','_')) as count from test) a
where count > 1
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=025302aab1f9061131ab85824327b4fc)